# Replace\Multiple lines on file using powershell

Tags: powershell

```sql
IF ( SELECT OBJECempErrorsT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors'() IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpErrors

GO 

CREATE TABLE #tempErrors (Error int) 

GO 

SET XACT_ABORT ON 

GO 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

Above portion of code is there on the sql file  multiple places and  I am trying to replace it with nothing '' or remove those  line from all the places from the sql file. I tried with

```bsh
$path = 'D:\Test.sql'

$replace = "IF ( SELECT OBJECempErrorsT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors'() IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpErrors

GO 

CREATE TABLE #tempErrors (Error int) 

GO 

SET XACT_ABORT ON 

GO 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED"

$output = 'D:\output.sql'

$Content = Get-Content -Path $path  -raw 

$Content -replace  $replace ,''| out-file $output
```

Any help  will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try the use of [here-strings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/)

Comment: one thing that likely is causing you a problem is the embedded `()` in your "to replace" pattern. those are regex symbols and need to be escaped. try using `[regex]::Escape()` on the whole thing. ///// also, as vrdse mentioned, you likely otta use a `here-string` for your multiline pattern.

Comment: Thank you Vrdse  and Lee_Dailey  for the solution. Combing both worked like a charm.